# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeEr ror: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: javascript, discord

So I'm creating a bot using discord.js-commando. Everything's working fine until I try and do a sendEmbed, where I then get the error

```
(node:25390) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeEr
ror: Cannot read property 'map' of null
(node:25390) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
 rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried to add a .then and .catch, but no luck so far. Probably because I have no clue how to make Promises work. >_>

I use the following code for the bot I'm working on that seems to be getting the issue.

```
const commando = require("discord.js-commando");
const modulestuff = module

class Test extends commando.Command {
constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
        name: 'test',
        aliases: ['testing'],
        group: 'random',
        memberName: 'test',
        description: 'Testing',
        examples: [ 'test' ]
    });
}

async run(message, args) {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(1);
    });
    var bot = new commando.Client();
    promise.then(message.channel.sendEmbed({
        color: 3447003,
        author: {
            name: bot.user.username,
            icon_url: bot.user.avatarURL,
        },
        title: 'Testing101',
        url: 'http://discord.gg/smv3NcP',
        description: 'This is a test command to see if the thing works.',
        Fields: [{
            name: 'Fields',
            value: 'Title Test',
        },
        {
            name: 'Masked Links',
            value: 'Let me see if I can embed a link into this. [masked links](https://discord.gg/smv3NcP)',
        },
        {
            name: 'Markdown',
            value: '*Testing* __101__ _101_ **__101__**'
        }
        ],
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
            icon_url: bot.user.avatarURL,
            text: 'Requested by ' + message.author,
    }})).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Something went wrong!!');
        done();
    }).then(function() {
        promise.then(message.channel.sendEmbed({
        color: 3447003,
        author: {
            name: bot.user.username,
            icon_url: bot.user.avatarURL,
        },
        title: 'Testing101',
        url: 'http://discord.gg/smv3NcP',
        description: 'This is a test command to see if the thing works.',
        Fields: [{
            name: 'Fields',
            value: 'Title Test',
        },
        {
            name: 'Masked Links',
            value: 'Let me see if I can embed a link into this. [masked links](https://discord.gg/smv3NcP)',
        },
        {
            name: 'Markdown',
            value: '*Testing* __101__ _101_ **__101__**'
        }
        ],
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
            icon_url: bot.user.avatarURL,
            text: 'Requested by ' + message.author,
        }}));      
    })
}};

module.exports = Test;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `promise.then(message.channel.sendEmbed({` is wrong unless somehow sendEmbed returns a function.  Promise then has two parts `.then(success, fail)`

Comment: @epascarello yep, sendEmbed is a promise, which means he should have put it inside a function instead.

Comment: I'm sorry for being such a noob in javascript, but wuuut? 99% confused right now :/